# scrolling datagridview without get focus

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to use wheel mouse and scroll vertical bar without actually get focus on datagridview in vb.net?

andrew

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scroll event to the form where the grid is found and scroll the grid by using the following article:

[Controlling scrolling with the API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/APIScroll.aspx)